# jQuery Multiselect Select First Element

Tags: jquery

I want to Select First element of drop down automatically when page load occur (using jQuery multiselect plug in)
Which property to be used ?

```
$('#cmbTicketStatus').multiselect({

  firstchild: 'selected', /* I Guess this is wrong */
  //  noneSelectedText: 'Select Ticket Status',
    selectedList: 1,
    selectedText: '# of # Status Selected'
}).multiselectfilter();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
$('#cmbTicketStatus select option:first-child').prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: phew just try it out? i think you could do

Comment: This is an extremely vague selector and could easily grab the wrong element.

Comment: @Jenson he hasn't read the doc, so you're going to have to spell it out for him

Comment: Because it can't be inside, needs to be later to the initialization unless you want to do it within the click function of the plugin itself.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to go after the multiselect function actually.. You are grabbing the plugin and then like other helpful people in here have commented out, need to use the native click.

```
          var o1= $('#cmbTicketStatus').multiselect("widget");
           o1.find(":checkbox").first().click();
```

Hope that helps/

Answer (score 0):

Sagar, 
Sorry for the delay, I did not receive a notification of your reply...

First element being a checkbox as it-s reworked by the plugin,
1.)  Find a set of checkboxes inside of the dropdown created by it:

```
            $("select").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").each(function(elem, index)
            {
```

ANSWER A: Using is :first, we know it-s $(this), but as well is the elem of the loop so either

```
                         if(   $(elem).is(":first")  )  this.click();
```

or

```
                         if(   $(this).is(":first")  )  this.click();
```

ANSWER B: We are looping through the elements constructed by the plugin, what a better place for a switch as we go through the loop?    index is the first element of the array, then obviously we have it on the first interaction of collecting the elements from the UI.

```
                              switch( index) 
                              {   

                                      case 0: this.click(); break;

                                      default: break;

                               }
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not by design but if you leave off "multiple=multiple" in the select element itself, the first option will be selected by default.

So instead of

```
<select multiple='multiple' id=myselect>
```

Simply do

```
<select id=myselect>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the multiselect plugin doesn't support choosing a selection, you have to manually trigger the click event to select:

Manually check or uncheck a checkbox?

The checkboxes can be accessed after calling the "widget" method. Simply manually trigger the NATIVE click event on them:

```
// manually check (or uncheck) the third checkbox in the menu:
$("select").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").each(function(){
   this.click();
});
```

The native click event must be used (trigger('click') will not work) due to this bug in jQuery’s core.

All necessary events and actions, like updating the button value, will automatically fire.

Alternatively, you could give the original option tag the selected attribute, and then call MultiSelect’s refresh method.

From: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/
Hopefully this is the same multiselect widget that you're using.

Comment: Yes i am using the same multiselect widget..but i am not able to understand what u r trying to tell. i just want to select first element automatically when page loads

Comment: This is helpful, however it will select every checkbox as it loops through it.. Sagar Dumbre, I have just reworked what jholloman supplied by adding some comments and few one liners depending on what works better for you.. sorry for the late reply.. Hope you have been able to solve this issue.